# MongoDB aggregation: Performance of queries with both indexed and non-indexed fields

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, aggregation-framework

Say I have a MongoDB collection of documents with only two fields - x and y - and one of them (say, x) has an index.

Will any of the following queries will have better performance than the other?

Single-match query:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$match : {x : "value", y : "value"}})
```

Double-match query (indexed field matched first):

```
db.collection.aggregate({$match : {x : "value"}}, {$match : {y : "value"}})
```

Comment: the answer you accepted is wrong - and the SERVER ticket it links is the reverse of your case - compound index and single query not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will any of the following queries will have better performance than
>   the other?

In a nutshell: no.  The performance will be more-or-less the same, at least as far as both of them will use the same index.

> db.collection.aggregate({$match : {x : "value", y : "value"}})

This will use the index on `{x:1}` the same way that a regular find() on x and y would use it.

> Double-match query (indexed field matched first):
>   db.collection.aggregate({$match : {x : "value"}}, {$match : {y : "value"}})

The first `$match` will use the index on x just like a find would.

In the first case the index is used to reduce the resultant set of documents to examine for matching y value.  In the second case the index is used to only pass through the pipeline the documents that match x so the second state would have to in-memory examine them for whether they match y.

This is basically the same operation in both cases efficiency-wise.

Comment: WTF you just said the exact same thing as me but instead you said " in-memory examine them for whether"

Comment: Also who is to say that if you only go on x to in memory scan y that more documents wouldnt need loading decreasing performance?

Answer (score 0):

The single match will have better performance since it can use a single index.

The double match is actually treated as a double `$match`, a.k.a a `$match` within a `$match` as such an index is not actually use for the second `$match`.

This behaviour however, has been changed in 2.5.4: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11184 so that multiple calls will just result in one call on the server. This is actually a bit of a bummer since it makes some queries that require a second non-indexed part harder now `:\`.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Hmm that's not what the JIRA says

Comment: For those downvoting my answer would be correct if he had a compound index, it's called misreading...

Comment: @AsyaKamsky to clear it up, I did say both would use the index, I thought he meant a compound index of `x,y`

Comment: wait, you realized now you misread the question but you're arguing that your answer is right anyway???

Comment: @AsyaKamsky No, I realised but didn't delete my other comments, check the times on the other comments